# Ubuntu terminal identifying Branch and Repository like Git Bash

Tags: git, ubuntu, terminal

Is there a way to get the Ubuntu terminal to show the name of the current branch like Git Bash for Windows?

I want to achive this:

[image: Git Bash displaying branch name]

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x157.html

Answer (score 0):

I have the following function to display the git branch (or tag) in my prompt:

```bsh
function new_parse_git_branch() {
    br=$(git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/')
    if [ "$br" == "(no branch)" ]; then
        echo "(git:tag:`git describe`)"
    else
        echo "(git:$br)"
    fi
}
```

If you run it in a git repository, it will display e.g.

```
(git:master)
```